# django admin inline with abstract class and m2m field

Tags: django, django-admin

This problem almost drives me crazy  :(

I was trying to use the StackedInline in admin interface.
The code below is in django documentation.

model.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

admin.py

```
class MembershipInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Membership
    extra = 1

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (MembershipInline,)

class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (MembershipInline,)
```

But if the Group is an abstract base class and PublicGroup is subclass that inherits from Group. Membership is used to relate PublicGroup and Person.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='%(class)s_Membership')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class PublicGroup(Group):
    pass

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

after running the command

```
python manage.py sql test
```

I got error "AssertionError: ForeignKey cannot define a relation with abstract class Group". 
After searching for solution, I know foreign key cannot point to a abstract class. Some solutions recommended to use generic relation. So I change the code again.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = generic.GenericRelation('Membership')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class PublicGroup(Group):
    pass

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    content_type = models.ForieignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey()
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

This time the command

```
python manage.py sql test
```

returns no error. But I got error when I try to add data on admin interface. The error says Membership is not a foreign key of PublicGroup. StackedInline  still doesn't work.

Now I really don't know what to do. Does anyone know how to achieve this function.
Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

Is there any good reason why you use this?

```
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

If possible, drop it, and then rebuild your database.

It might be interesting for you to read the answers to [this stackoverflow question about the difference between abstract models and regular inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655097/django-abstract-models-versus-regular-inheritance).

Comment: because `through='%(class)s_Membership'` only works in abstract class.

Comment: I've already read that answer and I think I need Group to be abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

Your model structure is terrible: a M2M relationship will build a relationship table for both Models you try to connect, just like "[Through keyword](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)" in M2M field

As I can see, you just want to build a M2M relation between Person and Model based on Group.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    type = models.CharField(max_lenght=32) # The Type of Group (Public/Private/etc..)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```