# Django Set Date against a Boolean Field

Tags: python, django, boolean-logic

I am very new in **python** and **django**.I am developing a website using django.I have given the user a option to upload content in my site.

But those content will be shown in the site if the admin approved it.For approval , I have added Boolean Field in my model just like that,

```
Class content(models.Model):

    content_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    content = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos', blank=False,null=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    uploaded_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

now whenever any content uploaded by user,first of all it stored in the database and by default the approved field remain False or you can say that the content is waiting for admin approval.

Then if admin approve it,then the content is allowed to show in the website.Its all going well. **But i want to track the the approval time**.

Remember that the admin can approve or click the boolean field after the content stored in the database.Now my question is, how can i track the approval time when the content is approved by the admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow a simple approach for this. Add a `created` and `modified` field for your model. So, whenever a user adds some content the `created` field will have the timestamp for the creation of content and when the admin approves the content `modified` field will have the timestamp for the approval of content.

You can use the following code for your model:

```
from django.db import models

class TimeStampedModel(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class content(TimeStampedModel):
    content_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    content = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos', blank=False,null=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

In fact, you can extend this practice to all your models to keep a track of when a field was modified and when it was created. Just extend the `TimeStampedModel` model for your model class.

Comment: but for huge amount of data transaction,will it be feasible?Don't You think that this approach will slow down the whole process?Because each time we have to call another model to add modified time.what do you think?

Comment: It does not call another model it **inherits** it. Basically, when you run `python manage.py syncdb` the `created` and `modified` field are added to all the models which have inherited `TimeStampedModel`. By creating another model I have just abstracted out the common code so that you don't have to include `created` and `modified` field in every model. You can just inherit them. You can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655097/django-abstract-models-versus-regular-inheritance

Comment: @archit I like your idea, but it will change modified whenever any field in the object changes.  That may be ok, but if not, another approach would be to hook into the validation code for the field in question.

Comment: @joelgoldstick Sure, that can be done. But if the OP has nothing to modify with the content once it has been uploaded, this approach would work just fine.

Comment: if i directly add a modified datetime field in my **photo** model,it will do the same job,isn't it? @archit

Comment: But i like your approach @archit

Comment: @Tanweer Yes, it will. The only reason I created another model was so that you could reuse the code. But if you have only one model you can directly add `created` and `modified` field in your model.