# django model reduce duplicate code

Tags: python, django

Here is my django model
Because I have `ProjectsArchive` and `StatusArchive` for saving history datas
You can see many fields are duplicate
I wonder how to reduce the duplicate code to make the code simple

```
class Projects(models.Model):
    title      = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    link       = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    state      = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    update_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
    ....

class ProjectsArchive(models.Model):
    title      = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    link       = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    state      = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    update_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True) 
    ....

class Status(models.Model):
    project             = models.ForeignKey(Projects, null = True, blank = True)
    state               = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    crawl_update_at     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)    
    ....
class StatusArchive(models.Model):
    project             = models.ForeignKey(ProjectsArchive, null = True, blank = True)
    state               = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    crawl_update_at     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)  
    ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer here: [Abstract base classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes)

According to your question, I will do:

```
class BasicInfo(models.Model):
    title      = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    link       = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    state      = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    update_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True) 

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Projects(BasicInfo):
    ....

class ProjectsArchive(BasicInfo):
    ....
```

After completing `BasicInfo`, You can reuse the `title`, `link` , `state` and `update_at`.

However we can create common model containing `state` and `crawl_update_at` for `Status` and `StatusArchive`.

```
class StatusInfo(models.Model):
    state               = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    crawl_update_at     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True) 

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Status(StatusInfo):
    project             = models.ForeignKey(Projects, null = True, blank = True)
    ....

class StatusArchive(StatusInfo):
    project             = models.ForeignKey(ProjectsArchive, null = True, blank = True)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a CommonModel where in you can put your redundant fields then whichever models you want to use them in just inherit CommonModel instead of models.Model.

```
class CommonModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    title      = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    link       = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    state      = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    update_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)

class ProjectArchive(CommonModel):
      any_new_field_you_want_to_add
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is abstract meta class.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/

```
class ProjectTemplate(models.Model):
    title      = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    link       = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    state      = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    update_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
    ....

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Projects(ProjectTemplate):
    pass


class ProjectsArchive(ProjectTemplate):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use inheritance.
Please look at the following link

[django abstract models versus regular inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655097/django-abstract-models-versus-regular-inheritance)

And also this the django docs about models (take a look at Abstract base classes)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/

Comment: Inheritance requires the two models to be linked (ie contains data on both tables) I don't think that is the intention.

Comment: Abstract base classes are useful when you want to put some common information into a number of other models.