# Django repetitive function in models

Tags: python, django

I have a group of model classes that all need the same function. Rather than define this function in every model class, is there a more concise way to do this?

```
class Archive(models.Model):
    source = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    total_size = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    number_of_files = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    number_of_files_transferred = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'archive'

    def as_dict(self):
    return {
        "source": self.source,
        "total_size": self.total_size,
        "number_of_files": self.number_of_files,
        "number_of_files_transferred": self.number_of_files_transferred
    }



class FullNightlyMetrics(models.Model):
    source = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    total_size = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    number_of_files = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    number_of_files_transferred = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'full_nightly_metrics'

    def as_dict(self):
    return {
        "source": self.source,
        "total_size": self.total_size,
        "number_of_files": self.number_of_files,
        "number_of_files_transferred": self.number_of_files_transferred
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just use classes? Make a base (abstract) model that has the method and have your "group of models" inherit from it. There's no special Django solution to this (other than making the model abstract so it doesn't create an unnecessary DB table).

Comment: What's wrong with `instance.__dict__`?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I wasn't sure if I could use an abstract class. How would it know about the fields of the tables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django abstract models versus regular inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655097/django-abstract-models-versus-regular-inheritance)

Comment: @CésarBustíos That seems to print out additional information "state" and "id" that I don't need in the dictionary

Comment: Besides the duplicate question (which I think will help you), here is a link to the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) for this.

Comment: You already have a bunch of duplication in the class models itself. I would just introduce a new field to hold the model type, unless you have  pressing need to have it in separate database tables (think of it as one table -- with the archived flag on)

Comment: @karthikr for organizational purposes they are in separate tables even though the fields are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define functions in abstract base model, and extend this base model in other models. The [documentation is here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes)

In your code, it would be like

```
from django.db import models

class CommonInfo(models.Model):
    source = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    total_size = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    number_of_files = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    number_of_files_transferred = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

    def as_dict(self):
      return {
          "source": self.source,
          "total_size": self.total_size,
          "number_of_files": self.number_of_files,
          "number_of_files_transferred": self.number_of_files_transferred
      }


    class Meta:
        abstract = True



class Archive(CommonInfo):

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'archive'


class FullNightlyMetrics(CommonInfo):

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'full_nightly_metrics'
```

Just have a try. I am not sure whether there is any bug in the code.
Hope that could help you.