# Django Models: Creating Subtypes

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am new to Django and am working through some models on a project right now.
Is there a decent way to set the following up?

Using a model that ties to the auth_user model (UserAccount), I prompt users to select the type of account they have (Ex: Vendor or Buyer).

This part works fine... but I want to build the site experience based off of their account type. How would I create VendorProfile or BuyerProfile models (with differing data) based upon that option?

I might be over analyzing this, but basically I do not want any profiles to be linked to both types of data. Is that something I should just control with views, or is there a good way to lock my models and prevent duplicate information? Let me know if you think this is too broad, but I'm still on the conceptual level.

So:

auth_user model

UserAccount model:
user: one to one (User)
account_type: 'V' or 'B'

VendorProfile(?)
user: one to one (UserAccount where type='v')?
company name:
vendor code:

BuyerProfile(?)
user: one to one (UserAccount where type='b')?
favorite color:
pet's name:

Comment: Check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655097/django-abstract-models-versus-regular-inheritance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can do that. for that you need to change a small thing in the auth table of django and that is you need to add a column account_type where the V or B will be stored. Hope you can find it how to do it.

next is create 2 models for vendor and buyer. make a onetoonefield with the user table for storing the id of the user, in this models keep the extra information of the vendor or buyer you want to store.

hope it helps

Comment: Ok, that might work @Exprator. Now at what level would I sort the user accounts into the vendor and buyer models? Would that be done through views, or can it be done at the model level... if that makes sense?

Comment: tweek the User model in the models.py and create the other two models. make the migrations and then according to the result you need perform the tasks in the view.py.

like in a view you want users whose account type are vendor.

User.objects.filter(account_type='the_one_you_want', pk=the_id)

Comment: Awesome! I figured I would probably use views for that, thanks for the tips @Exprator