# Django using Abtract model

Tags: django

I am new in Django.
There is abstract model in Django? 
how can I use it?
Do it create the tables both to base class and children?
I am try to understand the Django documentation in this topic but failed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django abstract models versus regular inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655097/django-abstract-models-versus-regular-inheritance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes there is abstract model.
you can use it by abstract=true in meta and it create the tables only for the children's!

example:

```
from django.db import models

class CommonInfo(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   age = models.PositiveIntegerField()

   class Meta:
      abstract = True
```