# How to access all fields in child class from base class in django?

Tags: python, django

Here is my models.py

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    start_date = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    last_date  = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    post_name  = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    education  = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    more_info  = models.TextField()
    type       = models.IntegerField()

    abstract = True

    def __str__(self):
        return "Upsc Jobs"

class Child(Parent):

    def __str__(self):
        return "Ssc Jobs"
```

Here how can I access all the fields from parent
class in child class while migration .

When I am doing this way with mysql databse. it is creating only 
one field for Child and that is `Parent_ptr_id`

Thanks..

Comment: You do not need this parent pointer. You can simply use `self.more_info`, etc. Since the properties are *inherited*, these are attached to that object.

Comment: sorry. i didn't get it.. please explain

Comment: Do you understand how inheritance in *Python* works? Let us ignore how it is "implemented" in the database (since that is not relevant here).

Comment: if i will use that way . using self.each fields then why i won't use all fields instead. i want better way if any. where we don't need to write anything.

Comment: but you do *not* need to write anything. You can just treat the `Child` object as if it has all the *inherited* columns as well (in fact it has). There is nothing special that needs to be done for inheritance.

Comment: sorry bro. m not able to understand .. could you please answer with code..

Answer (score 1):

The `abstract = True` should be inside `class Meta`:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    start_date = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    last_date  = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    post_name  = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    education  = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    more_info  = models.TextField()
    type       = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __str__(self):
        return "Upsc Jobs"


class Child(Parent):

    def __str__(self):
        return "Ssc Jobs"
```

But still, you should be able to access all fields of the Parent class on your Child object, just like Willem's answered.

However, regarding the migration part, the correct usage of the `abstract = True` should do what you want. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655097/django-abstract-models-versus-regular-inheritance) for clarification.