# filtering multiple models having a DateRange field as "validity_range"

Tags: python, django, django-models

Using the Django ORM, I have multiple models (A, B, C, A2B, B2C) who all inherit from a `ValidityMixinModel` that represents their validity period.

```
class ValidityMixinModel(models.Model):
    validity_range = DateRangeField(null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class A(ValidityMixinModel):
    Bs = models.ManyToManyField("B", through="A2B")


class B(ValidityMixinModel):
    As = models.ManyToManyField(A, through="A2B")
    Cs = models.ManyToManyField("C", through="B2C")

class C(ValidityMixinModel):
    Bs = models.ManyToManyField(B, through="B2C")


class A2B(ValidityMixinModel):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name="Bs_through", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, related_name="As_through", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class B2C(ValidityMixinModel):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, related_name="Cs_through", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    c = models.ForeignKey(C, related_name="Bs_through", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I would like to be able to filter all objects (A, B, C, A2B, B2C) that are valid on a given day in an easy way, something like:

```
with ValidityMixinModel.valid_on_context_manager(date(2018,11,23)):
    # only display objects A with their related Bs 
    # as if A, B and A2B instances had all the filter 
    # validity_range__contains=DateRange(date(2018,11,23),date(2018,11,24))
    print(A.objects.prefetch_related("Bs","Bs_Cs").all())
```

Any idea on how to do this ?

Comment: filtering or querying on `ValidityMixinModel` model should able to do that job.

Comment: I have updated my question to clarify a bit the setup. Could you explain how I could get the equivalent of `A.objects.prefetch_related("Bs","Bs_Cs").all()` by filtering on `ValidityMixinModel` (I am not a django expert ... yet)

Comment: sorry i missed a point earlier. As your primary goal is model-inheritance you should not you add `abstruct = True` in model meta field.  you can go through this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655097/django-abstract-models-versus-regular-inheritance) if you have any further question. I will try give a brief answer later.

Comment: My mixin class should have abstract=True as it is a mixin. I do not want model inheritance (as for polymorphism)

Comment: Are you only look to select a specific set of fields from each model? Or do you want each entire model including any differences between them. If it's the former look at Django's usage of `QuerySet.union()`. If the latter, you can't.