# How to fix fields clashes when using models multi-inheritance in django

Tags: python, django

Let's say we have a parent abstract model `AModel` that defines a field `foo`:

```py
class AModel(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    foo = models.TextField(max_length=500, db_index=True)
```

And we have two abstract model classes `BModel` and `CModel` those inherit from `AModel`:

```py
class BModel(AModel):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class CModel(AModel):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

And we have a model class `DModel` that inherits from `BModel` and `CModel`:

```py
class DModel(BModel, CModel):
```

The problem here is that `foo` field will clash with itself because it's defined in the two parent model classes.

How to solve this problem? Is there a "Django" way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: I'm not 100%, but I would guess the Python Method Resolution Order will automatically take care of it. If a class directly implements `foo`, that one will be used, and otherwise it will use a Depth-First left to right search for the field, in your case starting with `DModel`, then it's first parent `BModel`, finding it in `BModel`'s parent `AModel`.

Comment: @NicoGriffioen: The MRO indeed will linearize this. But Django's logic will inspect the parents, and indeed report a "clash".

Comment: @NicoGriffioen actually it's a problem I'm facing now, and indeed it reports a clash on the field being inherited.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible. You will need to modify the hierarchy of models.

Using `Python's inheritance + models.Model` also doesn't work. e.g. doing `class AModel:`, `class BModel(AModel):`, `class CModel(AModel):`, and then `class DModel(BModel, CModel, models.Model):` will not work.

Read [django abstract models versus regular inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655097/django-abstract-models-versus-regular-inheritance).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to mute the attribute either in `BModel` or `CModel` ?

```py
class AModel(models.Model):
  foo = models.TextField(max_length=500, db_index=True)

  class Meta:
    abstract = True


class BModel(AModel):
  # Inherit foo from AModel and add B-specific stuff
  bar = ...

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class CModel(AModel):
  # Inherit foo from AModel and add C-specific stuff
  baz = ...

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class CModelWithFooMuted(AModel):
  # Inherit foo and baz from CModel but mute foo
  foo = None

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class DModel(BModel, CModelWithFooMuted):
  # Inherit foo only from BModel and avoid clash
```