# How to declare abstract class and methods for model implementation?

Tags: python, django, django-models, metaclass, abstract-methods

I wonder if there is a way in Django to create an abstract class where I can declare a method that should be implemented in a model.

Normally, in Python, we declare abstract class like this:

```
import abc

class MyABC(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def do_something(self, value):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

And then implement it like this:

```
class MyClass(MyABC):

    def do_something(self, value):
        pass
```

What I did with django is:

```
import abc
from django.db import models

class MyClass(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __str__(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

class MyClass2(models.Model, MyClass):

    def __str__(self):
        pass
```

But this gives me error:

```
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

I don't understand what I did wrong here. `MyClass2` should inherit from `MyClass` and from `models.Model`.

What I did wrong? Why this is wrong? What is the better way of declaring methods that should be implemented in models?

Comment: Maybe, this link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/16838663/7320045

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For django model you can try this.

from django.db import models

```
class MyClass(models.Model):

   class Meta:
      abstract = True
   def __str__(self):
      raise NotImplementedError

class MyClass2(MyClass):

   def __str__(self):
       pass
```

refer [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes)
hope this helps.

Comment: I read this page a few times, but doc says nothing about methods. Anyway, this worked for me. Thanks! Maybe Django doc should have an example on how to do this.

Comment: @macieyn basically docs just clear the concept, which is good enough to understand. :-)

Comment: maybe my English is not as good as I think. Thanks a lot!