# Why is meta class giving an error for abstract?

Tags: django, metaclass

When I added `abstract = True` to this code:

```py
customUser(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    id = models.autofield(primary_key = True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'User'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Users'
        abstract = True
```

it is returing this error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model core.CustomUser' that has not been installed but settings.py is properly set.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Because it makes no sense to point to an abstract model as user model. How would you create such user if you register a new one, or log in?

Comment: Yes. `abstract = True ` means, it will not create a db table for that model. So, it can't be use as user model or use for authentication, login. Look here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16838663/13861187

Answer (score 1):

`abstract = True`  means, it will not create a db table for that model. So, it can't be use as user model or use for authentication, login.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16838663/13861187)

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to refer to a user model that is abstract. Abstract means that there is no table for that model. Typically abstract models are used to be inherited in other (non-abstract i.e. *concrete*) models.

So if you would use an abstract model as user model, then how would you register (i.e. create) new users, fetch these users to log in, etc.?

You thus should always refer to a non-abstract model as [**`AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#auth-user-model).